# Geometric intuition behind Cauchy not having a mean

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to follow the geometric intuition behind the Cauchy distribution in the book "An introduction to probability theory and its applications" by Feller volume 2, first edition. On page 51, he describes the density of the Cauchy distribution as:

$$\gamma_t = \frac{t}{(t^2+x^2)\pi}$$

He then describes an experiment where a ray of light is emitted horizontally onto a vertical mirror from a source O. The light strikes the mirror at point A and the mirror can rotate about a vertical axis passing through A. This is shown in the figure below. The light reflects off the mirror and strikes the wall O is on at a distance $X$ from O.

[image]

The first assertion is that if $\phi$ is uniformly distributed between $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, $X$ has the density given by $\gamma_t$. I managed to prove this. Then he says that its apparent that if this experiment is repeated $n$ times and the average taken, then this average $\frac{X_1+X_2+\dots X_n}{n}$ will have the same distribution as $X_1$. I didn't follow this part. I guess I could derive it from the density, but Feller seems to be hinting at some kind of obvious geometric intuition which I'm completely missing.

Comment: Not the answer, probably, but it might be relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36037/2546 https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36131/2546

Answer (score 2):

I have not read the book, but I think of it in the following way. For any one observation, you expect $x$ to be not that large, but there's clearly a possibility of drawing an angle $\varphi$ such that you get a *really* large $x$.

If you do this $n$ times and average all the distances $x_1, \dots, x_n$, then do you expect the average to "tighten up" at all? Will it start to hone in around $O$?

The answer is no. You can get angles $\varphi$ such that $x_{n + 1}$ is so extreme that the average jerks around as wildly as $x_1$. Informally I think of this as representing the idea that with the Cauchy distribution, more data doesn't help. There is no learning going on.

I don't know if that's geometric enough for you, but the point is that you are likely enough get distances so large that the average is no more informative than the first observation.

Comment: The claim is far more specific than that. It says that the average is itself Cauchy with the same distribution as $X_1$.

Comment: You asked for intuition. I'm saying that the average distance will behave like the first distance. 'More data doesn't help' means that the average will behave like the first observation.

Comment: Don't follow that part. More data doesn't help doesn't necessarily mean the average behaves like the first observation.

Comment: I'm not trying to prove it; the book already told you. I thought you just wanted some intuition as to why the result would be true. We know that you can get large values for $X_1$. The Law of Large Numbers usually tells you that the average converges to the expected value. Here there is no expected value, and that dovetails with that I'm saying about the average behaving just like the first observation. The next observation can be so extreme that it makes the average bounce around just like the first observation.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'm looking for something more rigorous than that.

Comment: Well, I can't predict that you want rigor when your post asks for intuition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a partial answer based on some insight I've collected so far in the hope that someone might be able to complete it. Let's simplify the problem and consider proving that $X_1+X_2$ has the same distribution as $2X_1$. $2 X_1$ implies scaling the distribution by $2$. And since $t$ is the scaling parameter of the distribution, it implies placing the mirror at $2t$ instead and repeating the experiment. So, we're basically saying that placing the mirror at $t$ and generating $X_1$ and $X_2$ and adding them is equivalent to placing the mirror at $2t$ and generating $X$. The $X$ has the same distribution as $X_1+X_2$. This becomes equivalent to proving that $\tan(\phi_1)+\tan(\phi_2)$ has the same distribution as $2 \tan(\phi)$ where $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ and $\phi$ are iid uniform random numbers between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.